# Why do multiple tomcat instances off of the same CATALINA_HOME require separate libraries?

Tags: tomcat, jar, jvm

I'm reading Tomcat: The Definitive Guide to learn how to deploy multiple instances of tomcat from the same installation.  They describe how you need to separate out the folders that are instance specific, thus leaving the core CATALINA_HOME stuff clean; this separation also provides the basis for clean upgrades between versions of tomcat as well.

A lot of the stuff they recommend pulling out into instance specific directories make sense, such as conf and webapps -- those folders contain the obvious application specific data.  However, the also recommend pulling out all of the folders that contain the jars that hold runtime classes.  To quote directly from their book:

> Also, some jar files and class files may need to be loaded from the shared, server, and common directory trees. This means that for multiple instances to work, each Tomcat instance has to have its own set of these directories; they cannot be shared by two differently configured Tomcat JVM instances.

Why would separate instances require their own jar files?  Is it not possible to point two concurrently executing jvm's at the same set of jar files?

Note: this is about tomcat 5.5 and 6.0

Comment: Which OS are they talking about? That might matter a lot…

Comment: @DonalFellows This is platform agnostic stuff as far as I can tell.  I'm sure they would have indicated otherwise as they do with respect to many other details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note, I'm answering my own question.  First of all, it's important to note that the reason you need to have your instance specific copies of the lib directories has nothing to do with concurrent jvm access to a single set of jar files.

The reason that you must copy these library files into your instance specific directory structures, also know as CATALINA_BASE's, is that in tomcat 5.5 and early 6.0 versions, tomcat could only use a single folder as the classpath source for the libraries found in shared, server and common.  This means that if a given tomcat instance requires additions or modifications of the libraries in these folders, you either must make entire new instance specific versions of shared, common, and server, or the modifications of the libraries, if done in CATALINA_HOME, will then affect ALL instances running off of that CATALINA_HOME.

Starting with TOMCAT 6.0.24 ( or so . . . ) the ability to load classes from shared, common and  server library folders both in CATALINA_BASE and CATALINA_HOME, gives the finer granularity of control so that your modifications can be put in the BASE, where they will override the HOME as necessary.  This means that you only need to put the specific modifications in your BASE; there's no need to copy over the whole thing.  And in fact there is quite a bit of configuration offered up in these newer versions of tomcat with respect to these libraries and their layered impact on the classpath of each tomcat instance.